# undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass [rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

To break down my app quickly: I have a songs, comments, and users model. User's can upload songs, and make comments.

I seem to be getting "undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass" error after submitting (creating) a song. If you go to [show#songs.html.erb](https://github.com/Apane/leap/blob/master/app/views/songs/show.html.erb) you'll see the comments code below. I've looked into how Ryan Bates does his comments and my code is identical. Not sure why strftime is't working. Please advise :)

Note: for what it's worth I'm running rails 4

**Full error msg:**

```
NoMethodError in Songs#show

Showing /Users/apane/Downloads/leap/app/views/songs/show.html.erb where line #34 raised:

undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #34):

<% for comment in @song.comments %>
<div class="comment">
<strong><%= link_to_unless comment.site_url.blank?, h(comment.author_name), h(comment.site_url) %></strong>
<em>on <%= comment.created_at.strftime('%b %d, %Y at %H:%M') %></em>
<%=simple_format comment.content %>
<p>
<% if can? :update, comment %>
```

Comment: It's `created_at` which isn't working. Possible cause is that you are not populating the field automatically (so it is `NULL` in the database, and `nil` in Ruby) in your `Comment` model.

Comment: Neil, how can I populate it automatically? is there a line of code that I should be adding to the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment.created_at is `nil` - this is your problem.
It is probably because you have created the comment but didn't **save** it yet
.
The created_at field will be filled only upon save.

Comment: I've added this line of code to the songs_controller "@comment = @song.comments.build" and this is where the problem lays as you've pointed out. How can I save the comments? if @comment.save etc.. perhaps?

Comment: Hi, one advice I can give you is to generate a new application, create some scaffold - like this for example 'rails generate scaffold Comment user:integer content:string' - then go over the generated code and see how things are supposed to work - I think it can be a very good lesson - enjoy :)